# Azure SQL hitting worker process cap ignoring pool size

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have to store a lot of rows in SQL. Here is some pseudo code in C# which I had:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataContext"].ConnectionString))
{
    await con.OpenAsync();
    var sc = new SqlCommand("InsertUpdateMyobject", con);
    sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", h.Code);
    await sc.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    // two more stored proc calls
}
```

I have moved 3 stored procedures into one, to limit the executions of sqlcommands. There is one int as output parameter which contains the scope_identity(). I have added this in my connection string:

> MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;ConnectRetryCount=3;ConnectRetryInterval=10;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=False;Max Pool Size=60

Also tried to add `Asynchronous Processing=true;` to the connection string.

I have set the `Max pool size` to 60 because I am using an S0 Azure SQL database. I do not want to scale up to S1, S2 or S3. I just want the code execution to not throw exceptions and just wait a bit longer before the next execution. I am running a console app with .net 4.6.2 so that the retry part in the connection string is supported.

When I run the sql part for about 100 times, I get one aggregate exception containing over 60 inner exceptions:

[image]

it's dutch and says something like:

Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

and below:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

My stored proc only does inserts and deletes on 3 tables and returns in an int (output param) the new primary key of one of the tables. (main, parent table which has 2 child,  tables)

seems a bit like this [Max pool size was reached error for parallel connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067751/max-pool-size-was-reached-error-for-parallel-connections)
but I have no datareader or table. There is just one int as output.
ps. this app is currently the only one hitting the azure db.

Comment: How many concurrent database operations does your entire application run at a given point in time?

Comment: 100 because I limited the mainobject collection to 100. But it will be 10.000+ in production... My only solution so far is to move back to run all sql in sync.

Comment: Can you run only 60 of them at a time?